# RegEx: Get every word until last 4 words

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have strings like

1. `wwww-wwww-wwww`
2. `wwww-www-ww-ww`

Many `w` separated with `-`
But it's not regular `wwww-wwww`, it could be `w-w-w-w` as well

I try to find a regex that capture every word until the last 4 words.
So the result for example 1 would be the first 8w's (`wwww-wwww`)
For 2nd example the first 5w's (`wwww-w`)

Is it possible to do this in regex? 
I have something like this right now:

```
^\w*(?=\w{4}$)
```

or maybe

```
[^-]*(?=\w{4}$)
```

I have 2 problems with my "solutions":

1. the last 4 words will not be captured for example 2. They are interrupted by the `-`
2. the words before the last 4 will not be captured. They are interrupted by the `-`.

Comment: Counting the delimiters might be a good idea, I can provide you with an `awk` solution, is it good enough?

Comment: Could you possibly reformat your post with full English?

Comment: i have a solution in php already. Just want to know if its possible just with 1 preg_replace

Comment: your examples are not very clear. Coud you add enough example to understand with input and desired output please?

Comment: Why `ww-ww-ww` has `Result: wwww`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible with a slightly more sophisticated lookahead assertion:

```
/\w(?=(?:-*\w){4,}$)/x
```

**Explanation:**

```
/       # Start of regex
\w      # Match a "word" character
(?=     # only if the following can be matched afterwards:
 (?:    # (Start of capturing group)
  -*    #  - zero or more separators
  \w    #  - exactly one word character
 ){4,}  # (End of capturing group), repeated 4 or more times.
 $      # Then make sure we've reached the end of the string.
)       # End of lookahead assertion/x
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oO7vG0/1).